# Shiny Dashboard Interactive charts

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a data frame headcount.df which looks like below:

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2762 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Worker ID        : chr  "1693" "1812" "1822" "1695" ...
 $ Job Posting Title: chr  "Accountant" "Business Analyst I" "Finance Analyst II" "Business Analyst V" ...
 $ State/Province   : chr  "Texas" "Michigan" "Heredia" "California" ...
 $ Country          : chr  "USA" "USA" "CRI" "USA" ...
 $ Worker Start Date: POSIXct, format: "2016-05-01" "2016-05-01" "2016-05-01" "2016-05-01" ...
 $ Worker End Date  : POSIXct, format: "2017-04-30" "2017-04-30" "2017-04-30" "2017-04-30" ...
 $ Labor Type       : chr  "Business Professional" "Business Professional" "Business Professional" "Business Professional" ...
```

as a note there may be duplicate records in here

I am able to create a chart using ggplot using the below

```
x <- "2017-03-03"
y <- "2017-10-31"
headcountbar <- headcount1.df %>%
    filter(`Worker Start Date`>=x & `Worker End Date`<=y) %>% 
    group_by(`State/Province`) %>% 
    summarise(Headcount = n_distinct(Worker))

ggplot(data = headcountbar, aes(x=`State/Province`,y = Headcount, fill = `State/Province` )) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position = position_dodge())
```

The above code only gives me a headcount of workers between the two dates, I would like to be able to break it by month/quarter as well.

I would like to use shinydashboard to make this more interactive where I can select the x axis to maybe show headcount by state over time range or headcount by labor type.

I know there is a lot in here so any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is very doable! If you're comfortable enough writing the code above, shiny will be easy for you! Just take some time and watch the [tutorials](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/). They really, really help when building an app.  

Once you're comfortable there you can add a checkbox to display the data by month, quarter etc.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will take a look at the tutorials. I can always follow along with the tutorials just fine but when trying to work with my own data that is a lot messier I tend to over think everything.